# Is there a way to write metadata to the docx file in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, metadata, docx

In Node.js, I'm able to write metadata in `pdf` file using `hummus` npm, but I also need to write metadata to `docx` file.

Please let me know if someone has suggestions for this.

Comment: Have you tried using `file-metadata` there is a good example [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-metadata)

Comment: it doesn't work. it only gets the metadata of the file. `write metadata` is the core of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A Docx file comprises of a collection of XML files that are contained inside a ZIP archive. The contents of a new Word document can be viewed by unzipping its contents.**

### So, to edit write docx file's metadata is to

1. Unzip the docx file.

you can use [unzipper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unzipper) npm to unzip docx file.

```
  fs.createReadStream('path/to/archive.zip')
    .pipe(unzipper.Extract({ path: 'output/path' }));
```

2. Once unzip the docx file, you can see `app.xml` and `core.xml` files in `docProps` directory, and update this as you require for the metadata of the docx file.

3. Zip the entire folder. It's ***important*** that the files that make up the docx are not within another folder, i.e. [Content_Types].xml must be in the root of the resulting zipped file.
   When you open (or extract to the current directory) the zip file, you should have something similar to the following:

```
./docProps/
./word/
./_rels/
./customXml/
./[Content_Types].xml
```